# how to convert string like "5cm" into an integer

Tags: python, string, list

I have an input list like `[2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]` and I would like to have a result:

`[2,3,4,5,6,2.5]`

I would like to start in this way

```
for element in inputList:
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/2174255

Comment: OP seems to have a float in there too. So, that is of no use.

Comment: @Nile thank you nile, but doesnt work for 2.3 cm it returns 23

Comment: Do you really want to ignore the suffixes? `2.5km` is much bigger than `5cm` but if  you convert them to `2.5` and `5` you lose that. Parsing the units would be somewhat more complicated, but probably also much more useful in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not use `regex`: :

```
my_list = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]

def get_digits(s):
    return ''.join(ele for ele in s if not ele.isalpha())


def convert_to_nums(my_list):
    result = []
    for ele in my_list:
        if isinstance(ele, (int, float)):
            result.append(ele)
        else:
            ele = get_digits(ele)
            try:
                result.append(int(ele))
            except ValueError:
                result.append(float(ele))
    return result
```

Result:

```
>>> convert_to_nums(my_list)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2.5]
```

Comment: This will do the wrong thing if given a number in scientific notation, e.g. `6.02e23`. The `e` will get stripped out, leaving the very different number `6.0223`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> lis = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]
>>> r = re.compile(r'\d+(.\d+)?')
>>> [float(r.search(x).group(0)) if isinstance(x,str) else x  for x in lis]
[2, 3, 4, 5.0, 6, 2.5]
```

Use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `float` to get `5.0` as `5`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [literal_eval(r.search(x).group(0)) if isinstance(x,str) else x  for x in lis]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2.5]
```

Starting your way:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
ans = []
r = re.compile(r'\d+(.\d+)?')            #regex to match an integer or decimal 
inputList = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]
for element in inputList:
   if isinstance(element, str):          #if element is a string then apply the regex
       num = r.search(element).group(0)  
       ans.append(literal_eval(num))
   else:
       ans.append(element)               #else append the element as it is
print ans
#[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2.5]
```

Another solution, considering your inputs are always valid ones:

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> allowed = '-+.' + digits
>>> allowed                        #allowed characters
'-+.0123456789'
>>> lis = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]
>>> ans = []
for item in lis:
    if isinstance(item, str):
    # if item is a string
        num = ''               # Initialize an empty string
        for c in item:         # Iterate over the string, one character at time.
            if c in allowed:   # If the character is present in `allowed` then
                 num += c      # concatenate it to num
            else:
                break          # else break out of loop
        ans.append(float(num)) # Append the float() output of `num` to `ans` or use 
                               # `ast.literal_eval`
    else:
        ans.append(item)
...         
>>> ans
[2, 3, 4, 5.0, 6, 2.5]
```

Comment: thanks but this is my first year with python and we didn't take this in school yet (regex) , it should be an other way , an easier one like with float int ...i dont know how

Comment: @user2471076 I've added another solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

inputList = [2, 3, 5, "2", "2.5km", "3cm"]
outputList = []
for element in [str(i) for i in inputList]:
    match = re.match(r"([-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?).*", element)
    if match:
        outputList.append(float(match.group(1)))

print outputList
```

This solution uses [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the numeric part from a string. `re` is an extremely useful module with which you should definetely make yourself aquainted.

Because regular expressions only work on strings, we first have to convert those list elements that are numbers to strings. We do this, using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `[str(i) for i in inputList]`

If you write `print [str(i) for i in inputList]`, then you'll get:

```
["2", "3", "5", "2", "2.5km", "3cm"]
```

So it's almost the same list as it was before, but the numbers are now strings.
Now, using this we can create a regular expression, that recognizes numbers. I didn't make that one up myself, it's from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#simulating-scanf) (`%f`). We match each element from the stringified list to that pattern and convert the resulting string to a `float` which we append to the `outputList`.

Note that in some locales, the decimal point (`\.`) may be represented by a different character. If this is important in your situation, you can receive the current locales decimal point character as follows:

```
import locale
locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"]
```

I hope the explanation makes it a bit clearer to you, what's going on - if not, please comment below.

Comment: thanks but I'm just amateur, this is my first year with python so I don't understand this
I was thinking about something like conveting in simple way with float, int ...

Comment: gimme a minute and I'll add an explanation. it's not difficult at all

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but shouldn't `inputList = [2, 3, 5, "2", "2.5km", "3cm"]` be `inputList = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]` ?

Comment: yeah, right. I just entered some random stuff into the list. but of course it also works with `[2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]` and any other similar list...

Comment: Of course! But in your answer you used both `[2, 3, 5, "2", "2.5km", "3cm"]` and `["2", "3", "4", "5cm", 6, "2.5km"]`. It seems (to me) a bit incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

First, use a regular expression: it's the right tool for the job. Second, use the simplest solution that will work for your known requirements: specifically, a regular expression that we can use to remove non-digits from the end of the string.

```
import re

vals = [2, 3, 4, "5cm", 6, "2.5km"]

rgx  = re.compile(r'\D+$')
nums = [float( rgx.sub('', str(v)) ) for v in vals]

print nums
```

And if you really must shun regular expressions, here's a way to do it without resorting to exception handling, type checking, or any logic more complex than the simplest `if-else`.

```
def leading_digits(v):
    for c in str(v):
        if c in '0123456789.': yield c
        else:                  return

def intfloat(s):
    f = float(s)
    i = int(f)
    return i if i == f else f

vals = [2, 3, 4, "5cm", 6, "2.5km", '8.77cm extra junk w/ digits 44']
nums = [intfloat(''.join(leading_digits(v))) for v in vals]

print nums   # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2.5, 8.77]
```

Comment: Nice, and I agree ``re`` is the right way to do this. But your solution gives ``[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 2.5]`` which is not precisely what the OP wanted.

Comment: I agree with your @FMc, and you win the wordcount. I'm such a stickler for technicality... should have been a lawyer I guess.

Comment: @VelimirMlaker I relented -- can't resist a puzzle, I guess. Happy Father's Day, Velimir, whether you're a son, a father, or both!

Comment: Nice coupling of generator and list comprehension, there! And "reading" the string from left to right...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more (probably least elegant), if you can't stand regular expressions:

```
input = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]
result = list()
for ele in input:
    while type(ele) is str:
        ele = ele[:-1]  # Strip off one letter from the end.
        for tt in (int, float):
            try: 
                ele = tt(ele)
                break
            except:
                pass
    result.append(ele)

print result
```

Comment: Using bare `except` is generally not a good idea. PS. I wrote my answer while you published yours, sorry... it's not a copy!

Comment: Sure, I mean my complete solution is "not a good idea" -- just golfing for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution inspired by @Akavall and simplified with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
def get_digits(s):
    return ''.join(ele for ele in s if not ele.isalpha())

def convert_to_nums(my_list):
    return [literal_eval(d) for d in (get_digits(s) for s in map(str, my_list))]
```

Result:

```
>>> my_list = [2,3,4,"5cm", 6,"2.5km"]
>>> convert_to_nums(my_list)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2.5]
```